Exporting analysis issue on Compass DataAnalysis software
I need help exporting an analysis of Compass DataAnalysis software by BRUKER. I want to include the chromatogram, mobilogram, and spectrum in one analysis and output them as an XY file.
Using the help (I had never used VB before), I succeeded in exporting only the spectrum analysis as an XY file. I noticed that the other two analyses I wanted to export are completed in the background.
Here is what I scripted:
Dim TIC   
Dim EIC   
Dim Mobilograms    
Dim EIM     
Dim ExportPath 
   
Set TIC = CreateObject("DataAnalysis.TICChromatogramDefinition")    
Set EIC1 = CreateObject("DataAnalysis.EICChromatogramDefinition")    
Set EIC2 = CreateObject("DataAnalysis.EICChromatogramDefinition")   
Set EIM1 = CreateObject("DataAnalysis.EIMMobilogramDefinition")   
Set EIM2 = CreateObject("DataAnalysis.EIMMobilogramDefinition")   
   
EIC1.Range = "808.8-809.8"   
EIC2.Range = "1516.4-1616.8"   
EIM1.TimeRange = "0-0.5"   
EIM1.Range = "808.5-809.5" 
EIM2.TimeRange = "0-0.5"   
EIM2.Range = "1516.5-1616.5" 
   
Analysis.Compounds.Clear 
Analysis.Chromatograms(1).ClearRangeSelections   
  
Analysis.Chromatograms.AddChromatogram TIC 
Analysis.Chromatograms.AddChromatogram EIC1 
Analysis.Chromatograms.AddChromatogram EIC2 
 
Analysis.Chromatograms(1).AddRangeSelection 0, 0.5  
Analysis.Chromatograms(1).AverageMassSpectrum false, true  
 
 
Analysis.Mobilograms.AddMobilogram EIM1 
Analysis.Mobilograms.AddMobilogram EIM2 
 
ExportPath= "D:\Data\testing code" & Analysis.Spectra(1).name & ".XY" 
Analysis.Spectra(1). Export ExportPath, daXY 
 
Analysis.save 
 
 
form.close

I added also below the
  ExportPath= "D:\Data\testing code" & Analysis.Spectra(1).name & ".XY" 
        Analysis.Spectra(1). Export ExportPath, daXY 

this command
ExportPath= "D:\Data\testing code" & Analysis.Mobilogram(1).name & ".XY" 
Analysis.Mobilogram(1). Export ExportPath, daXY

However, I got an error of not existing project or method.
Could you please help me with this?

I tried your script and it works well.
You didn't have the correct object defined. I used the following, and it works:
Analysis.Mobilograms.Item(1).Export exportPath & "Mobilogram_808_809.xy", daXY


Thanks a lot Aria. Works perfectly!!! You made my day.
